# Confused about this integration when solving the differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving this exact differential equation 
$$\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right) dx+\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{1}{y}\right) dy=0$$
I was confused about the following integration : 
$$\int \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx=tan^{-1}\left(y/x\right) $$
or does it have to be 
$$\int \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx=- tan^{-1}\left(x/y\right) $$
the same for the following integration , it can take 2 values, which one is right?
$$\int \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy=tan^{-1}\left(y/x\right) $$
$$\int \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy=-tan^{-1}\left(x/y\right)$$
But I think that $$tan^{-1}\left(y/x\right)\ne -tan^{-1}\left(x/y\right)$$

Comment: Note that :$$tan^{-1}(y/x)+tan^{-1}(x/y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: $$y(x)=Cx$$ is one solution

Comment: You missed $+C$ for indefinite integrals

Comment: i see the $$C$$ control the solution and plug them in the equation

Comment: @Khosrotash $\frac{\pi}{2} \text{sgn}(x/y)$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how did you know that $$y(x)=Cx$$ is a solution ? can you clarify ?

Answer (score 1):

plugging $$y=Cx$$ in your equation we get
$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{Cx}{x^2+(Cx)^2}+\frac{Cx}{x^2+(Cx)^2}-\frac{1}{x}=0$$

Comment: But I see that we can get this solution by guessing , can we get it from the integration ? ( I mean are there any steps to get this solution? or just we guessed ! )